# PHP foreach echos a specific array item twice

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I take a PHP basics course in teamtreehouse.com and in this course I learn about PHP loops. Regarding PHP `foreach` loop, I wrote this code which works fine:

```
<?php

$items = array(
    'item1' => 'X',
    'item2' => 'Y',
);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
}
```

> X
>
> Y

And yet, when I try to target a specific item after iterating foreach element this way:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $items['item1'];
}
```

The output is `XX` instead just `X`.

My question is why I got `XX` in the first place and an answer could help me understand how to extract the specific value I want (the value of the first key-value pair - `X`) with `foreach`.

Comment: thats how the loop work..it begin with condition and ends on a condition no matter what you do inside..here your foreach will iterate number of times it has elements inside which are here 2 and you are accessing the item by its key `echo $items['item1'];` so as result you are printing same value twice

Comment: In the second loop you select and print the value assigned to the `item1` index in the assoc array. The value assigned is `X`, hence it prints X as many times as there are pairs in the array.

Comment: if you want to print just the first items in list do  `echo list[0];`

Comment: I think I understood it now. Please review my own answer if you want. I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different things happening:

- printing the current value from the array for each iteration
- printing referring to the same item by key for each iteration

This array has 2 items:

```
$items = array(
    'item1' => 'X',
    'item2' => 'Y',
);
```

Now if you loop the array using a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), you can use your syntax like:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item . "<br>";
}
```

Now you are using `$item`, which is the current item in the foreach. In this case, this will print 2 different values for each iteration: "X" and "Y".

Now looking at the second part of your code:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $items['item1'];
}
```

Now you are using `$items['item1'];` for each iteration. That means that you are referring to the item in `$items` with the key `item1` which has the value of "X". That is why you are getting  "X" and "X".

If you direclty want to get an item from the `$items`, you can do that like this:

`$items["item1"];`

If you want to use a foreach to get the item where the value is "X", and you know that the key is "item1", you could for example do it like this:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
    if ($key === "item1") {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` function iterates through an array as many times as the number of elements in array, which are 2 (first element is with key `item1` and second element with key `item2`) here in your example.

The code to access first element in your array is `$items['item1'];` which upon print/echo will output the value at this key (`item1`) which is `X`

Since the `foreach` function iterated twice, so it executed the code inside it twice as well, which in your case was printing a value `X` (hence printing two times at the end of iteration)

Just to extract the particular value you can use `echo $items['item1']`; (extracting value at `item1`, for example) without foreach loop (since you donot require going through every element here in your array)

for instance, you can try the following code:

```
<?php

$items = array(
    'item1' => 'X',
    'item2' => 'Y',
);

echo $items['item1'];
```

which will have the following output

```
x
```

You will need to use `foreach` only in case when you need to go through all your array to execute some functionality, for accessing a specific element or even for just searching you don't need to use `foreach` as there are many better functions for arrays in php.

Answer (score 0):

For each item, as there is two item in the object(the loop is running two times), you're echoing the first item. That's why its showing "xx".

Answer (score 0):

You should know another usecase of foreach:

Foreach will loop every element in array, as well as every {key & value} element.

You can use following code:

```
$items = array(
    'item1' => 'X',
    'item2' => 'Y',
);

foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
    echo $key. ":" . $value . "<br>";
}
```

This will print

> item1:X
>
> item2:Y

Answer (score 0):

Here's why I got `XX` from my code.

```
<?php

$items = array(
    'item1' => 'X',
    'item2' => 'Y',
);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $items['item1'];
}
```

With the expression `echo $items['item1'];` I **dictated** the loop to negate `'item2'`. Thus, it treats only to data in the index of `'item1'`, but given the `echo` is for both the first value of `$items` and `['item1']` itself, the value is printed twice: Once as a variable expansion of the first value of `$items`, and second, as from expanding its first value itself with `['item1']`.

This is just how the `foreach` function of PHP is built.

To affirm this philosophy I did:

```
$items = array(
    'item1' => 'X',
    'item2' => 'Y',
    'item3' => 'Z',
);

foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $items['item1'];   
}
```

And got: `XXX`.